# How to avoid Docker images with Repository and tag <none> while building an new Image

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am trying to build a new docker image. And this is how my Dockerfile look like

```
FROM docker-standard-all/dev_env_g3_g5:latest

WORKDIR /root/

COPY controller.pom.xml .
COPY docker_settings.xml .
COPY stage.sh .

RUN mkdir ~/.m2

RUN ln -sf ~/docker_settings.xml ~/.m2/settings.xml

# Initialize Maven repository
RUN mvn dependency:resolve -f controller.pom.xml -q

ENTRYPOINT ["./stage.sh"]
```

After building a docker

```
docker build -t bc/controller-in-docker:1.0.2" "${PATH}"
```

When i perform

```
docker images -a
REPOSITORY                                          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
bc/controller-in-docker                             1.0.2               a32e212bc0f7        2 hours ago         2.41GB
<none>                                              <none>              f4e68f5a2720        2 hours ago         2.41GB
<none>                                              <none>              b71751242efd        2 hours ago         2.4GB
<none>                                              <none>              26e3a086889c        2 hours ago         2.4GB
<none>                                              <none>              4acf1759940a        2 hours ago         2.4GB
<none>                                              <none>              0d66510e6a67        2 hours ago         2.4GB
<none>                                              <none>              adc5c7038a4b        2 hours ago         2.4GB
<none>                                              <none>              a994c54e00af        2 hours ago         2.4GB
docker-standard-all/dev_env_g3_g5                   1.17.4              6a83d123f497        6 months ago        2.4GB
```

After a bit googling and stack over-overflow, I just realized that : containers are not dangling containers. In fact they appeared to be formed after running the commands like COPY, RUN etc in Dockerfile.

Questions:

1. What is the overall size of my new docker images? My each none:none container appears to occupy ~2.41GB from terminal output. In total they all add unto 2.4 * 7 GB
2. Can I delete these none:none Images ? They are not dangling images for sure. But they are occupying 2.4 GB each (not sure though) and also confusing name associated with them.
3. Is it possible to avoid these none:none images while building the new docker Image ? Any suggestions/modifications to the Dockerfile in order to avoid them?

Thanks

Comment: Please avoid asking multiple distinct questions in one single question - rather open multiple questions that focus on a single question each

Comment: "They are not dangling images for sure." . How have you made this conclusion? They may have been created from a previous build. Make a test, prune them, remove `bc/controller-in-docker` image, rebuild and check again. If none of these `none:none` are present, then they were dangling images.

Comment: @leopal . I have deleted all my images & containers before starting anything. After the Image is built i tried all these  ` docker images -f dangling=true`   `docker system prune` ,`docker system prune -a`  but nothing got deleted.

Answer (score 0):

docker images -a will always show lots of “none” images since it shows every layer of every image. If you run, for instance,

```
docker history docker-standard-all/dev_env_g3_g5:1.17.4,
```

you should see all of the intermediate layer IDs. Those are included in the `docker images -a` output and can’t be removed.

To remove all dangling Docker images:

```
sudo docker rmi $(sudo docker images -f “dangling=true” -q)
```

If run as root omit "sudo"

```
docker rmi $(docker images -f “dangling=true” -q)
```